Power BI how to group by using a conditional statement
I am looking for successful quotes as defined by "Bound"
The data is showing each option offered to the client as one row.
If 2 options were offered I want to combine into one quote.
For example the top 2 rows are one quote with 2 options.
The bottom 3 rows are 2 quotes with 2 bound or successes. A third option was offered as part of the 2 quotes.

When I group by Insured Name and Quote Initiation Date it works for the top 2 rows in that it combines to one quote that was not successful.
However the bottom 3 rows group to 1 quote that was successful as opposed to 2 quotes.

You need to provide sample input and sample output, properly describing how to get from input to output (what defines which are separate quotes? Which columns get acted upon? What is the action supposed to be? etc) . Please edit your question or I doubt anyone can help you

Seems logic to me as you also need to group also on the "Issue Date" when you want the result you are looking for.

Could you create a conditional "Is_Success" column and check the status to be "Bound" and set it to True, else False. Then group by Name and this new column?
